# Access properties of long chained JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

This seems to be a strange doubt but would like to know about it.

In my vanilla javascript project, have to access different properties inside an object.

Consider

```
{
students: {
 insideProperty1: {
  insideproperty2: {
   insideProperty3: {
    pro1: 1,
    pro2: 2,
    pro3: 3,
    .
    .
    .
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I have to access the inside properties

Do i use

```
students.insideProperty1.insideProperty2.insideProperty3.pro1
students.insideProperty1.insideProperty2.insideProperty3.pro2
students.insideProperty1.insideProperty2.insideProperty3.pro3
```

or

```
const proVar = students.insideProperty1.insideProperty2.insideProperty3;
proVar.pro1
proVar.pro2
proVar.pro3
```

what i asked is my script will be optimised and compressed in production (using uglifyjs and others), so do i need to take care of this in development or does the optimisation scripts take care of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even make more shorter with array destructing.

```
const { pro1, pro2, pro3 } = students.insideProperty1.insideProperty2.insideProperty3;
```

Answer (score 1):

The later.

1) It is more readable (thats what matters after all)

2) It is shorter (less code -> less code to load -> loads faster)

In your code you create thousands of variables, allocate millions of objects and arrays. One variable does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to read all the properties of you just want some of them also it depends on the total number of properties in the JSON.
Suppose you have only 3 properties in your JSON it will be better to use the first method because it will take up lesser memory , but if you want to read all the properties and the number of properties is large , you should go with the second method.